# Evitar que hibernate me cree la tabla con Id?

Tags: hibernate

al meter una tabla en hibernate me crea la tabla pero me genera otra con Id.
Por ejemplo: Clientes.java y ClientesId.java.
Alguien sabe como solucionarlo? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

le has creado el id a tu  tabla, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
 @Id
 @Column(name="CLIENTE_ID")
 private Long clienteId;
```

saludos.

Comment: Como puedo evitarlo?